# Javascript async function return then-catch promise?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

### Introduction

I am new in the world of javascript promises and I need to understand how they work correctly...

Until know I have been doing this in my code:

```
  const handleRefresh = () => {
    setIsRefreshing(true);

    fetchUserData()
      .then(async () => { <--------- Using then because I return a promise in fetchUserData
         await fetchUserPosts(); <------- Using await here
         setIsRefreshing(false);
      }).catch(err => { <--------- This will catch the error I have thrown in the function fetchUserPosts or inside the then body
       // TODO - Show error
       setIsRefreshing(false);
       console.log(err)
    );
  };

  const fetchUserData = async () => { <------ async function
    const { firebase } = props;

    const userId = firebase.getCurrentUser().uid;

    const documentRef = firebase.getDatabase().collection("users").doc(userId);

    // Fetch all the user information
    return documentRef <--------- Returning the promise here
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          // Get all user data
          const data = doc.data();
          console.log(data);
          setUserData(data);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        throw err; <----------- Throwing error
      });
  };
```

I don't know if I am doing anti patterns... But basically I need to know if this is a good way and if I am doing this correctly.

### Questions

1. Do I have to declare the fetchUserData function as async to return a promise?
2. Can I use the async await in the then/catch body?
3. Can I do this?

   ```
   const handleRefresh = async () => {
    setIsRefreshing(true);

    await fetchUserData()
      .then(async () => { <--------- Using then because I return a promise in fetchUserData
         await fetchUserPosts(); <------- Using await here
      }).catch(err => { <--------- This will catch the error I have thrown in the function fetchUserPosts or inside the then body
        // TODO - Show error
        console.log(err)
      );
      setIsRefreshing(false);
   };
   ```

I would really appreciate if someone guides me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the words `async` and `await` are only syntactic sugar for `then` and `catch`.

This:

```
  fetchUserData()
    .then(data => return data )
    .catch(error => return error)
```

is equivalent to:

```
 async function getUserData() {
   const userData = await fetchUserData()

   return userData
 }
```

Here you are returning anything (success or error). If you want to treat the error here, just put a try/catch clause.

```
  async function getUserData() {
   try {
     return await fetchUserData()
   } catch (e) {
     return e.message
   }
 }
```

Note that you can only use the `await` clause within an `async` function.

Comment: And will the error I throw on fetchUserData() and fetchUserPosts() be catched in the same catch block?

Comment: No, you'll need a try/catch block for each async function call.

Comment: `@Pablo Darde`  I may misunderstood your above comment, but any error raised within `try` will be caught by `catch`, so theoretically you can use one `try` for multiple Promises

Comment: I suppose he tried to say that if I want to handle multiple errors, if one error is catched, then the second that follows (in the same try statement) will not be catched because the function call will never be done.

Answer (score 1):

**1.**
Function can return `Promise` without being declared as `async` as long as you don't await inside it,

**2.**
You should not use `async-await` inside `then`, simply return a Promise and it'll be resolved in the following `then`,

**3.**
When using `async-await` syntax, Promises are awaited in a declarative way as demonstrated below:

```js
const handleRefresh = async () => {
  try
  {
    const a = await getA()
    // pass the result to another Promise
    const b = await getB(a)
    const c = await getC(b)
  
  } catch (error)
  {
    handleError(error)
  } 
};
```